# Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm with this error and I'm trying to capture and write about the user's node> email doing so but still giving error, could someone help me? any help is welcome.
the node email already has the comma but when it comes to recovering I still get the error I'm trying to modify the node when receiving with the code below.

my code

```
 addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            final String userUid = user.getEmail();

            final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            ref.child("users").child(user.getEmail().replace(".",",")).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("cassinotime",dataSnapshot.child("cassinotime").getValue(String.class));
                        map.put("cassinoprofit",dataSnapshot.child("cassinoprofit").getValue(String.class));


                        ref.child("users").child(user.getEmail()).child("cassino").child("cassinotime").setValue(map);
                        ref.child("users").child(user.getEmail()).child("cassino").child("cassinotime").setValue("50000");
                        ref.child("users").child(user.getEmail()).child("cassino").child("cassinoprofit").setValue("250");


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

---

register code

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            User user = new User(


                            );
                            String photoUrl = null;
                            if (account.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                                user.setPhotoUrl(account.getPhotoUrl().toString());
                            }

                            user.setEmail(account.getEmail());
                            user.setUser(account.getDisplayName());
                            user.setUid(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                            user.setMoney(money);
                            user.setCassinotime(cassinotime);
                            user.setCassinoprofit(cassinoprofit);

                            FirebaseUtils.getUserRef(account.getEmail().replace(".", ","))
                                    .setValue(user, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                            mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            dismissProgressDialog();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You should delete this characters from name of your database

Comment: Have you manually imported "users" data in firebase ?

Comment: I didn't send it manually.

Comment: @Upz91, check `user.getEmail().replace(".",",")`, as you are already doing that, put on log and check

Comment: Emails have .com not ,com

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the email as a parent node for the user's details, it is better to use the `userId`:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUid();
ref.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Answer (score 1):

While storing email as a path, I recommend you to encode the email i.e., replace 'dots' from 'commas'. If you want to retrieve, you can decode.

```
public static String decodeString(String string) {
        return string.replace(",", ".");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you noticed the screenshot, it already has a comma.

Comment: Does this email send by you, Right?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. check my post edited. how am i doing the user registration via google auth.

Comment: before `user.setEmail(account.getEmail());` you just decode string and then after set.

Answer (score 1):

In these three lines of code:

```
ref.child("users").child(user.getEmail()).child("cassino").child("cassinotime").setValue(map);
ref.child("users").child(user.getEmail()).child("cassino").child("cassinotime").setValue("50000");
ref.child("users").child(user.getEmail()).child("cassino").child("cassinoprofit").setValue("250");
```

You are still using the original `user.getEmail()` value.  You should use the encoded string like you did in the query.  Just do it once and store it in a variable, then reuse the variable.

Even better, just make the reference once and reuse it:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference()
    .child("user")
    .child(user.getEmail().replace(".",","));
```

Then in the callback:

```
ref.child("cassino").child("cassinotime").setValue(map);
ref.child("cassino").child("cassinotime").setValue("50000");
ref.child("cassino").child("cassinoprofit").setValue("250");
```